# benchmarking trig lookup tables performance gains vs cpp implementation

Tags: c++, benchmarking, trigonometry, lookup-tables

We are developing a real-time system that will be performing sin/cos calculations during a time critical period of operation.  We're considering using a lookup table to help with performance, and I'm trying to benchmark the benefit/cost of implementing a table. Unfortunately we don't yet know what degree of accuracy we will need, but probably around 5-6 decimal points.

I figure that a through comparison of C++ trig functions to lookup approaches has already been done previously.  I was hoping that someone could provide me with a link to a site documenting any such benchmarking.  If such results don't exist I would appreciate any suggestions for how I can determine how much memory is required for a lookup table assuming a given minimum accuracy, and how I can determine the potential speed benefits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer all your questions, but instead of trying to determine theoretical speed benefits you would almost certainly be better off profiling it in your actual application. Then you get an accurate picture of what sort of improvement you stand to gain in your specific problem domain, which is the most useful information for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

What accuracy is your degree input (let's use degrees over radians to keep the discussion "simpler").  Tenths of a degree?  Hundredths of a degree?  If your angle precision is not great, then your trig result cannot be any better.

I've seen this implemented as an array indexed by hundredths of a degree (keeping the angle as an integer w/two implied decimal point also helps with the calculation - no need to use high precision float/double radian angles).

Store SIN values of 0.00 to to 90.00 degrees would be 9001 32 bit float result values.

SIN[0] = 0.0
...
SIN[4500] = 0.7071068
...
SIN[9000] = 1.0

If you have SIN, the trig property of COS(a) = SIN(90-a)
just means you do
SIN[9000-a]
to get COS(a)

If you need more precision but don't have the memory for more table space, you could do linear interpolation between the two entries in the array, e.g. SIN of 45.00123 would be

SIN[4500] + 0.123 * (SIN[4501] - SIN[4500])

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know the performance characteristics of the two approaches is to *try them*.

Yes, there are probably benchmarks of this made by others, but they didn't run in the context of your code, and they weren't running on your hardware, so they're not very applicable to your situation.

One thing you can do, however, is to look up the instruction latencies in the manuals for your CPU. (Intel and AMD have this information available in PDF form on their websites, and most other CPU manufacturers have similar documents)

Then you can at least find out how fast the actual trig instructions are, giving you a baseline that the lookup table will have to beat to be worthwhile.

But that only gives you a rough estimate of one side of the equation. You might be able to make a similar rough estimate of the cost of a lookup table as well, if you know the latencies of the CPU's caches, and you have a rough idea of the latency of memory accesses.

But the only way to get accurate information is to try it. Implement both, and see what happens in *your* application. Only then will you know which is better in *your* case.